# iOS: How to get the 'primary' ABPersonRef out of the array of linked contacts that ABPersonCopyArrayOfAllLinkedPeople returns?

Tags: ios, contacts, addressbook

According to documentation `ABPersonCopyArrayOfAllLinkedPeople`

> "returns an array of all person records in the address book database
>   that are linked to the given person record".

but I see no clue on how to get the ABPersonRef within this Array that the user/iOS has choosen/set to be the 'primary' contact (i.e. that is shown in the contacts app.)?

**Update:** 
The following screenshots should make it clearer what I am talking about:
Suppose you have the simulator standard contacts **(pic 1)** and for whatever reason you decide that Kate and Anna are actually the same person - then you can link those two. Choose Kate, click edit Kate **(pic 2)**, click Link **(pic 3)**, select Anna **(pic 4)**, confirm the linking **(pic 5)** - then the contact app will show only Anna **(pic 6)**. When I query ABPersonCopyArrayOfAllLinkedPeople on Anna or Kate then it returns both Anna and Kate. But programmatically I have no way of telling which ABPersonRef is the one the standard contact app chooses displays.

Pic 1:
[image: 1]
Pic 2:
[image: 2]
Pic 3:
[image: 3]
Pic 4:
[image]
Pic 5:
[image]
Pic 6:
[image]

Comment: Ok now I got your problem, so I have deleted my answer as it was not according to your question. Now I will try to solve this problem and answer again if possible.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code to get the primary contact

```
NSString *primaryContact   = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABPersonCopyArrayOfAllLinkedPeople(kABPersonPhoneMainLabel);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - but I am somewhat suprised about your code. ABPersonCopyArrayOfAllLinkedPeople returns an CFArrayRef and takes a ABPersonRef as an argument. How do you want to cast it to an NSString and use a CFStringRef as an argument? Furthermore what has PhoneMainLabel have to do linked contacts? May be I am missing something big here or my question was not as clear as I thought. Could you explain a bit more how this is supposed to work? Sorry, but I am really not understanding it and could't get it working in xcode either)...